# confusion over using c# Predicate

Tags: c#

I have a following list of `IEnumerable<>` and i am looking for a value in it. It returns me true if it's there:

```
  RepositoryForDashboard rp = new RepositoryForDashboard();
  IEnumerable<ListOfAuthorizedUserForTestDashBoard> usersForT = rp.listOfusersForT();
```

the value is "username" and i look up like this:

```
 if(usersForT.Any(e=>e.userID==username))
```

it works fine, but since I am new in c#, I want to learn how should I write it using Predicate delegate, this gives me error:

```
   Predicate<string> isInList=delegate(username){usersForT.Any(e=>e.userID==username)};
```

Comment: There are syntax errors at your code, the bracket for closing the .Any and the return keyword

Comment: The only reason to write something as a delegate is if you need to; e.g. if you needed to pass that code as an argument to some other method.  Depending how often (in how many places in your code) you need to call this query it may be worth extracting this logic into its own function; but if it's just a one off it can stay as you've got it.

Comment: @HanyHabib edited,the same error

Comment: I added you an answer for using Lamda expression, which syntax easier or if u need delegate kindly update the code mistakes and include the error

Comment: @JohnLBevan can you take me an example  in which scenario i should pass code as an argument so some method?thanks in advance

Comment: No worries, done... hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your code, you can use lambda also which will make it easier for you ex :

`Predicate<string> isInList = item => usersForT.Any(e=>e.userID==item);`

Or if using a delegate, include a type and a `return` statement:

```
Predicate<string> isInList = delegate(string username) { 
    return usersForT.Any(e=>e.userID==username); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested in the comments, here's an example of using code-as-a-variable.  In this case the function `UserMatchingCriteriaExists` on the user manager accepts a single predicate used to test whether any user matching the given criteria exists.  By having this function accept a predicate rather than simply the username, given name, and surname, we allow the method to be more useful than the coder of that class could have imagined.  E.g. The current logic just filters for matching strings based on an AND of the provided criteria; which is pretty simple.  However, if someone using our `UserManager` has a use case where they want to find all usernames which are in upper case, or those where the first name matches the surname, etc, our `UserMatchingCriteriaExists` method can handle that; the client just needs to create the required predicate.

[Dot Net Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ubFtyq) (tweaked slightly from the below to work in the older version of C#).

```
void Main()
{
    //create a reference to our user manager
    var userManager = new UserManager();

    //run some demos with different search criteria
    SearchAndDisplay(userManager, null, "Anne", "Droid"); //should return true
    SearchAndDisplay(userManager, null, "Anne", "Borgue"); //should return false
    SearchAndDisplay(userManager, null, "Simon", "Borgue"); //should return true
    SearchAndDisplay(userManager, "Two", null, null); //sshould return true
    SearchAndDisplay(userManager, "Four", null, null); //should return false
    SearchAndDisplay(userManager, null, null, null); //should return true (as we've not given any filter criteria, and users do exist)
    SearchAndDisplay(new UserManager(true), null, null, null); //should return true (as we've not given any criteria, but no users exist so there is no match)
}
void SearchAndDisplay(UserManager userManager, string searchByUsername, string searchByGivenName, string searchBySurname)
{
    //build up our query
    Predicate<User> searchCriteria = And<User>(); //`And` with no arguments is simply `true`
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchByUsername)) searchCriteria = And<User>(searchCriteria, user => searchByUsername.Equals(user?.Username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchByGivenName)) searchCriteria = And<User>(searchCriteria, user => searchByGivenName.Equals(user?.GivenName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBySurname)) searchCriteria = And<User>(searchCriteria, user => searchBySurname.Equals(user?.Surname, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    //search the users using the criteria defined above; NB: The user manager does not need to know anything about our query logic, so our client has lots of flexibility in what queries it can use / is not restricted by the UserManager's implementation
    var result = userManager.UserMatchingCriteriaExists(searchCriteria);

    //display some output to show the user what we've done
    Console.WriteLine($"Search Criteria:\n\tUsername: {searchByUsername ?? "not searched"}\n\tGivenName: {searchByGivenName ?? "not searched"}\n\tSurname: {searchBySurname ?? "not searched"}\nFound: {result}");
}
///Holds basic user information
class User 
{
    public User(){}
    public string Username{get; set;}
    public string GivenName{get; set;}
    public string Surname{get; set;}
}
///Holds the collection of users & allows operations against them
class UserManager 
{
    readonly IEnumerable<User> users;
    public UserManager(): this(false) {}
    public UserManager(bool noUsers)
    {
        if (noUsers) 
        {
            users = new User[]{};
        }
        else
        {
            users = new User[]
            {
                new User(){Username = "one", GivenName = "Anne", Surname = "Droid"}
                ,new User(){Username = "two", GivenName = "Simon", Surname = "Borgue"}
                ,new User(){Username = "three", GivenName = "Alex", Surname = "Arnold"}
            };
        }
    }
    public bool UserMatchingCriteriaExists(Predicate<User> criteria)
    {
        return users.Any(user => criteria(user));
    }
}
///Allows us to combine predicates
Predicate<T> And<T>(params Predicate<T>[] predicates)
{
    return delegate (T item)
    {
        foreach (var predicate in predicates)
        {
            if (!predicate(item))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```